# Where to host static assets? HTML, JS, CSS and MP3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, static, mp3, twilio

I used up my free year of Amazon S3. Is there somewhere I can host an mp3 file (with url: "http://.mp3")

Also, where can I host a directory full of html, js, and css files? These assets will respond to a Rails API.

Comment: Look at GitHub Pages.

Comment: Yup, realized this a few hours ago. Thanks!